# use polar coordiantes and the Poincare-Bendixson Theorem.

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates, fixed-point-theorems

I am searching for some help with this question in review for a upcoming exam, I have been having some trouble understanding the workings that have been provided and am just looking for some clarification.

The question says to show that,

$$x'=x+y-x(x^2+2y^2)$$
$$y'=-x+y-y(x^2+2y^2)$$

has at least one periodic solution. The hint given was to use polar coordiantes and the Poincare-Bendixson Theorem.

So using polar coordiates,

$$r'=\frac{xx'+yy'}{r}=-r(F(\theta)r^2-1)$$ 
So how did they calculate  $$-r(F(\theta)r^2-1)$$

and my final question is how does this next step come about? How did they calculate $F(\theta)$

$$F(\theta)=cos^4\theta+2sin^4\theta+3cos^2\theta sin^2\theta=1+sin^2\theta $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We calculate

$$r'=\dfrac{xx'+yy'}{r} = \dfrac{1}{2} r^3 \cos 2 \theta-\dfrac{3}{2}r^3 + r = -r\left(\left(\dfrac{3}{2} - \dfrac{1}{2} \cos 2 \theta \right)r^2 - 1 \right) = -r(F(\theta)r^2-1)$$

where

$$F(\theta) = \left(\dfrac{3}{2} - \dfrac{1}{2} \cos 2 \theta\right) = 1 + \sin^2 \theta$$

**Update**

From $\cos 2 \theta = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta$, we have

$$\left(\dfrac{3}{2} - \dfrac{1}{2} \cos 2 \theta\right) = \dfrac{3}{2} -\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta\right) = \dfrac{3}{2} -\dfrac{1}{2}\left(1 - \sin^2 \theta\right) + \dfrac{1}{2} \sin^2 \theta = 1 + \sin^2 \theta$$

Comment: how did you calculate $1+sin^2\theta$?

Comment: Please see update.